# Tableau 10 String Manipulation

Tags: string, tableau-api

I am using Tableau 10 and need to figure this out.  I have one customer's  whose  name has 3 different variations.

**Example**

Customer id 1000  Brown Joe

Customer id 1000 Brown Joe Jr

Customer id 1000 Brown, Joe.

How do get the name to read as  `Brown Joe`.

I need the Jr to be removed from the first scenario and the comma removed from the second scenario.

Comment: Is this the only scenario you have; "remove the commas" and "remove the Jr s"?

Comment: The others on the list are the same did not want to repeat the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IF CONTAINS([Name],"Jr")
THEN SPLIT([Name],' ',1)+ " "+SPLIT([Name],' ',2)
ELSEIF CONTAINS([Name],",")
THEN SPLIT([Name],',',1)+ " "+SPLIT([Name],',',2)
ELSE
[def]
END
```